# shop in vs shop at

Tags: prepositions

If I want to get something when I go abroad then can I use a sentence like
"I made a shopping list in Canada", 'I'll shop a pair of sunglasses in Canada' and 'Shopping in CA'(This is the title of my memo)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

No. The preposition "in" is connected to the verb, not the shopping list. The sentence

> I made a shopping list in Canada

means that you went to Canada, and then made a shopping list there. That would be a very boring holiday! Instead, you would say "I made a shopping list for the trip to Canada" which in common speech you can shorten to "I made a shopping list for Canada."

> I'll shop a pair of sunglasses in Canada

The verb "to shop" is an intransitive verb, which is a fancy word for saying that it doesn't have a direct object<sup>*</sup>. Instead, you shop *for*  a pair of sunglasses.

> Shopping in CA (this is the title of my memo)

Keep in mind that readers from the USA will interpret this as "Shopping in California" rather than "Shopping in Canada".

A memo is a piece of writing sent within an organisation or company. I don't think you mean to forward your shopping list to your boss. "Shopping in Canada" would be an OK title for a shopping list, although I would just title it "Shopping list for Canada".

<sup>* Arguably, "to shop" can be used as a transitive verb meaning "to Photoshop", that is, digitally edit an image. This would mean you went to Canada, opened up an image processor and edited an image of sunglasses. Your holiday keeps getting more boring...</sup>

Comment: Another alternative for the title would be to use "Canada" as a noun adjunct modifying "shopping": **Canada shopping list** or just **Canada shopping**.

Comment: *Shop* can also be used in the sense of making a sales pitch to someone about something. (*I shopped my idea around to various distributors.*) Also, I *am* Canadian, and even I interpret *shopping in CA* as meaning *shopping in California*! ;) I obviously understand CA to stand for Canada in certain contexts, but this is not one of them.